# CISCO ASA 5505 Base Licence - Ability to interpret http request headers (host headers)

Tags: routing, cisco-asa, http-headers, host-headers

Base licence configured CISCO ASA 5505 is not capable of routing based on interpretation of the inbound http request headers - affectively host header redirect - am I correct?

If I am correct will an upgrade from the base licence help me - or is device not the best for this type of requirement, and if so, please recommend a similar device (budget wise) that is.

If am not correct, and a base licence configure Cisco ASA 5505 will do this, please advise...

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to do at the firewall level? route to different IP's based on host headers?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "routing based on interpretation of the inbound http request headers". Routing is based on L3 protocols - i.e. IP most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about using the ASA 5505 to listen on a public IP address and route, at layer 7, requests to different web servers behind it based on the "Host:" header specified in the HTTP request.

This isn't something that the ASA devices have ever been able to do, to my knowledge.

You could do this with an HTTP reverse proxy, like Apache (or any number of other reverse proxies). If you want something commerical-off-the-shelf, Microsoft ISA Server can do this, too.

Comment: Yes, route to a different internal IP based on host headers - I think we need a device which is more a content switch than this basic firewall.

Comment: @Klaptrap: Absolutely. The Cisco ACE line will do what you want, or you can use software like Apache, ISA Server, etc.

Comment: Going to route via the ISA server - which is only currently used for outbound traffic.  Should be our cheapest option without upgrading the Firewall.